# How to delete all sub folders with name "test" in C#

Tags: c#, subdirectory

I am new to C#. I have to delete sub folders starting with name "test.number" test.1 test.2 test.3 .... present in C:\ directory. These folders are not empty. What is the best way to achieve this?

I tried using directory.delete

```
try 
{ 
    Directory.Delete(@"C:\test", true); 
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

but this deletes folder with name test leaves the rest

Comment: and the error you got?

Comment: I want to achieve deleting test*

Comment: @Madhava: You already said that. But *what happened* when you tried what you showed in your question?

Comment: the second argument to .Delete is if you want it to be recursive so this should work unless you have some other kind of issue

Comment: I want to achieve deleting all folders starting with name test

Comment: @Madhava: What happened when you tried doing so?

Comment: my code deletes folder named test. But I have test1 test2 test3 so do I have to use a loop?

Comment: @Madhava: Please put that information into your question and we're getting closer to what a question should look like to receive useful answers :-)

Comment: @Madhava: Sorry for closing; after you had updated your question, I undid my downvote, but I couldn't undo my close vote :-(

Comment: no problem :) I got it working :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
  var testDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\", "test.*");

  foreach (var directory in testDirectories)
  {
      Directory.Delete(directory, true);
  }
```